# OneDrive: How do I determine if a file is at the top level of the users' OneDrive directory?

Tags: onedrive

I'm trying to find the location of a specific file in OneDrive.

I'm using the /search REST API to do this.

If I search on a file name and the file exists in three places, I get a parent_id for all three files in the results, even if one of the locations is the root directory.

If I subsequently query for file data on the parent_id for the root directory, I get a 404.

Shouldn't the parent_id be null for a file in the root directory?

Is there any way to know that the path ID that will come back as 404 corresponds to the root directory?

Answer (score 2):

At app startup do a query on:

```
https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/skydrive
```

This will give you back a small json blob about the root folder, including it's "id" member.  All the files in the root should have this same ID for parent_id.  Example for me:

```
GET https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/skydrive
200 OK
{
   "id": "folder.1234567812345678", 
   ...
   "name": "SkyDrive", 
   "description": "", 
   "parent_id": null, 
   "size": 17656182301, 
   "upload_location": "https://apis.live.net/v5.0/folder.1234567812345678/files/", 
   ...
}
```

So that's how you can detect what the ID for the root folder is. The root folder has an id, but it's parent_id is of course *null*.

> If I subsequently query for file data on the parent_id for the root directory, I get a 404.

That's weird, if I invoke this:

```
GET https://apis.live.net/v5.0/folder.1234567812345678/files
```

I get back the same exact results as if I had queried for `/me/skydrive/files`

I suspect your URL is malformed.  What does the URL look like when you invoke that call that returns back a 404?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. The call that gets me a 404 is:

https://apis.live.net/v5.0/folder.12ea4b6cbf3ee803.12EA4B6CBF3EE803!123

I'm trying to convert a filename to an ID, so I'm marching up the chain, querying parent_id and then doing "https://apis.live.net/v5.0/" + parent_id.

In this case, where the parent_id is theoretically the main Skydrive folder, I get

404 - {
   "error": {
      "code": "resource_not_found", 
      "message": "The resource 'folder.12ea4b6cbf3ee803.12EA4B6CBF3EE803!123' doesn't exist."
   }
}